# Unable to post comment via external keyboard on mobile devices

Tags: bug, comments, keyboard, mobile-chrome

Generally I can post a comment by pressing Enter key on my PC keyboard right after typing it.

> [image: comment]

But when I use external bluetooth keyboard on my iPad, I can’t do this, pressing the Enter key just does nothing (using the Shift+Enter I can add new line into comment text). In the same time search panel in the top bar is working as expected - pressing Enter just start searching.

Comment: This is fairly likely to have been a browser/OS/driver stack/hardware issue rather than an issue with SE's HTML/JavaScript. Additional testing would be needed with your hardware and setup. At a minimum, it would have been quite beneficial to find a contrasting webpage UI element where your use of the enter key did end up submitting such an input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue now looks fixed somehow. Enter key posts the comment.

Tested on the same iPad (now with modern iPadOS 14.7.1) on Chrome 93.0.4577.39